# Oracle - Select all records based on one distinct column, table with many columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to select all records from a view but disctinct on one column.  The view has many colums so I don't want to place disctinct before all columns within the query ; and they  may increase

e.g.

```
post_code   name    last_name   col_a   col_b   col_c   col_d   col_e col n...
A1 123  Abi      Smith          a       a       a       a       a       
A1 123  Barb    BarbLastName    b       c       d       b       c       
B1 123  Cart    CartLastName    b       c       d       b       c       
C3 123  Dilbert DilberLastName  b       c       d       b       c       
D4 123  Edgar   EdgarLastName   b       c       d       b       c       
D4 123  Fred    FredLasName     b       c       d       b       c
```

so something like select * records by distinct post code and return all the first (or any) of them

```
A1 123  Abi      Smith          a       a       a       a       a       
B1 123  Cart    CartLastName    b       c       d       b       c   
C3 123  Dilbert DilberLastName  b       c       d       b       c   
D4 123  Fred    FredLasName     b       c       d       b       c
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

How do you choose the row that you want?

You can use `row_number()` to get an arbitrary row:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by post_code order by dbms.random) as seqnum
      from (<your query here>) t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: @solarwind . . . May I ask why you unaccepted the answer?  (You can accept whatever answer you like; I'm just curious.)